# Best way to pass multiple data types

Tags: c++, plugins, frameworks

I'm programming a plugin framework, the plugin is supposed to pass data to the application, I created a queue where the plugin puts the data, but I want that the plugin can pass multiple data types (int, bool, char, ...) and not only one.

Any ideas or any good way to do that?

Comment: Just use chars and cast everything back to what it is supposed to be.

Comment: Thanks! That can work. I'll give it a try (Can you post it in an answer?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use chars and cast them to just about anything. For the data types you can't "get to" with simple casting I suggest using memcpy().

Comment: Could you post an example of what you mean? Here is one interpretation of your response that potentially corrupts memory and does not always work as intended in C++: `int i1 = 0x7FFFFFFF; /*max value of signed 32-bit int*/ char* c = new char(); /*char is 8 bits on most systems*/ memcpy(c,&i1,sizeof(i1)); /*trying to fit four 8-bit bytes into 1 byte*/ int i2 = *c; /* casting back to int */ printf("%s",(i1 == i2 ? "TRUE" : "FALSE")); /*should print TRUE if i1 and i2 are equal as intended, but it does not*/`. Without an example, I will down vote as your response is potentially misleading.

Comment: For starters, you can't fit a 32 bit value in an 8 bit data type. You will have to make use of a char array to fit an int in there. 'int i1 = 0x7FFFFFFF; /*max value of signed 32-bit int*/
    char c[sizeof(int)]; /*char is 8 bits on most systems*/
    memcpy(&c[0],&i1,sizeof(i1)); /*trying to fit four 8-bit bytes into 1 byte*/
    int *i2 = (int*)c; /* casting back to int */
    printf("%s",(i1 == *i2 ? "TRUE" : "FALSE")); /*prints true*/'

Answer (score 5):

If using the [boost library](http://www.boost.org/) is an option, I would highly recommend using [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost/any.html):

```
boost::any a(1234567);
boost::any b(12.3456);
boost::any c(12345LL);
boost::any d(true);
```

Comment: I'm trying to reduce the requirements inside my plugin library, but thanks, I'll take a look!

Answer (score 1):

Use templates and other generic programming techniques as part of your design.

Here's a starter on templates:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/

Using boost any is most recommended, but an alternative that I think is better from a design perspective than the current accepted answer (if you want to minimize dependencies) is the following very simple implementation of a template wrapper that accepts and returns any type:

```
class IAnyType {}

template <class T>
class AnyType : public IAnyType
{
private:
    T value_;
public:
    AnyType(T value) : value_(value) {}

    void set(T value) { value_ = value; }

    T get() { return value_; }
};
```

Then, just make your queue hold IAnyType objects and store all arguments inside an AnyType object before adding it to the queue. You could certainly spruce this up a bit by overloading various assignment operators and make usage even simpler.